# Can't connect to wireless 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I have ubuntu installed as the sole OS on a T420. Before this I had installed the #! distro (and Xubuntu before that) and wireless worked seamlessly on either. My home hotspot shows up but when I click on it tries for a while before disconnecting.

Before going into the problem further, I wanted to double check that I entered the wifi password for my home network correctly. I went to Edit Connections >> Wi-Fi Security and changed the key, but it is still not able to connect. So I think the password is definitely correct. I don't understand why it can't connect now.

Comment: Could you please try to remove the current access-point by changing to the directory. Using a terminal `cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` & `ls` to list down all saved AP's.. Once you noted your AP, issue `sudo rm you_access_point_name` to remove & restart your network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`.. see whether it helps! :)

Comment: @AzkerMohamed it did indeed :) Thanks! Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I've posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try to remove the current access-point by changing to the directory. Using a terminal

- Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & type below command in a sequence;

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections      # locate all the stored network profiles
ls                                             # list down the network profiles
sudo rm you_access_point_name                  # removes the specified profile
```

- Restart your network manager with;

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

- Try connecting to the WiFi once restarted.

Hope it helps!

Comment: recently on two ubuntu installs the wifi network was no longer seen (possiblty caused by an update), following your steps and doing a restart fixed it