# Wireless connection wt 2000 pci

Tags: network-manager

In windows 7 I connected to an wireless network tp-link with no problem using dhcp and wifi card wt 2000 pci,but after I installed ubuntu 14.04 and when I connect to the same network it connects but no internet also using dhcp,I tried also manualy adding the ip address but still the same it connects with no internet,so where is the problem there?

Thank you all for answers.

```
jasmin@jasmin-desktop:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:64412 (64.4 KB)  TX bytes:64412 (64.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:4f:6a:05:ca:df  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::24f:6aff:fe05:cadf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:138298 (138.2 KB)  TX bytes:109630 (109.6 KB)

jasmin@jasmin-desktop:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
jasmin@jasmin-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Remove your [**WiFi saved profiles**](http://askubuntu.com/a/418029/179042) first and then try connecting again without assigning IP addresses. After, please post the output for `ifconfig`, `ping google.com` & `route -n`. :)

Comment: there are my outputs in question area

Answer (score 0):

Install ndiswrapper

```
sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf
```

Check the driver is working:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
```

Load the module:

```
sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi up and working!