# Guest Wireless/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, wireless-access-point

At work i have to connect to a guest wireless network. This usually requires me to acces 1.1.1.1/login.html to complete the connection using a set username and password that changes every week. I see the guest wi-fi on the list of available networks, I click on it, trys to connect and never does. Eventually it says offline again. Never bringing me to login page listed above. Any ideas.

BTW - I was able to login to my private wi-fi network at home with no problems. I also tried it at Starbucks today and had no issues.

I also tried to login to this Guest Wi-Fi using a windows machine and had no issues either.

Not sure what to check since I an ubuntu virgin (only 3 days old). i did look in the System Settings>Software&updates>additional drivers> and noticed a was using the following:

Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary) was selected. No other options were available under wirelessbg/n controller.

===============================================
RESOLUTION:

LP#1010931 14e4:4727 [Dell Vostro 3555] Broadcom BCM4313 5GHz doesn't work but 2.4GHz does

The root cause is the card is single-band only, so it would never broadcast at 5GHz.
To fix the 14e4:4727 on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04, uses brcmsmac :

sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
Then you need to blacklist b43 and wl driver like this:

echo "blacklist b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

sudo modprobe -r b43 wl brcmsmac
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
echo "brcmsmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules

Comment: have you tried setting your browser to the url 1.1.1.1/login.html before you login in case it is a problem with automatically re-directing you to this page?

Comment: Hi & welcome to **AU**. I'm not sure whether this is the case, but try to look into [**Can't connect to wireless 13.10**](http://askubuntu.com/a/418029/179042) & do accordingly, then try connecting. If it helps, please comment.

Comment: Yes, I actually pulled up the page and kept refreshing it while it was trying to connect and never came up. Here are some info on my card in case you guys need it: BCM4313 802.11bgn wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev01)

Comment: I did try the following as well and this did not work: cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections      # locate all the stored network profiles
ls                                             # list down the network profiles
sudo rm you_access_point_name

Comment: well did you exactly removed your AP profile by replacing its original SSID name to `you_access_point_name`??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands in a terminal

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 15
```

and see if that doesn't help.

This sets your retry limit from the default of 7 to 15. The default is set at 7 to increase battery time and to use less power but in cases of public wifi and weak signals, this can cause issues, especially when trying to connect to the network. When your computer sends a signal that is not answered, it will retry instead of giving up so easily.

Comment: Seems to be keeping the connection now(sporadically) but auth page (https://1.1.1.1/fs/customwebauth/login.html) page never loads. I went to it manually but it doesnt come up (unable to connect)

Comment: @HeinzSeijas It may be rejecting you because of your mac address. I will post a solution above.

Comment: posted it the fix on my question section since I was not able to close this due to restrictions (new user)

Comment: @HeinzSeijas you should be able to post that as an answer ( you can answer your own question and accept it )